# C# asp. I am trying to take a txt file from a user and rename it then upload it to azure file storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

There is no easy way to rename a file in azure file storage or any cloud tags i could find to do so. We want to be able to change the name so that we can organize files inside azure file storage. Since it is from a file off the users desktop we were having problems with this. We tried many ways to get this to work and currently I was trying to move the contents of the file into a variable through StreamWriter StreamReader and file streams something kind of like this. I know the naming convention is terrible and the code is totally broken but its just to give an idea of the direction I was heading.

```
            fs1.Position = 0;
            string halpme;
            TextWriter sw44 = new StreamWriter(fs1);
            sw44.WriteLine(halpme);
            sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            StreamReader SR2 = new StreamReader(fs1);
            sw44.Write(SR2);
```

then we were going to create a new file with something sort of like this however I'm not entirely sure this would work for this instance

```
 File.WriteAllText((Server.MapPath("~~~~") + "test.txt" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")), halpme);
```

Then use halpme as the variable to input the contents. Then upload this new file instead however since this is going to be a website I'm not sure that is the direction I wanted to head. I'm not a beginner, as you can see I'm somewhat over my head in this project but I'm also not amazing.  This is unrelated to school but I'm going back to college in a couple weeks and I want to fully understand anything you could provide so please treat me like I'm stupid and explain it almost to an annoying degree. This is just the idea I came up with on how to solve this problem if you have a better solution I would also love to hear it.

Comment: Can you access the file name? If so, simply write the file to a path locally with the new name, and than use that file to upload to Azure, then if you want to, remove the original file.

Comment: originally we tried that but we were denied access since its web based users would have to click and agree to a download as far as I know. If you know a way around that that would work.